# How do I access Looking Glass Knight?

Tags: dark-souls-2-sotfs

How do I access the Looking Glass Knights door in Scholar of the First Sin? I've made my way around to unlock the other way and have beaten the annoying Gargoyle. The elevator is still up and I can't pull the lever.

Comment: ...am I missing something? The Belfry Gargoyle is nowhere near the Looking glass knight...

Comment: @Ben In SOTFS, where you go around to the other side to unlock the door, there is only a single archer, but a single Gargoyle comes out to attack you.

Comment: @Ben The screenshot is from regular Dark Souls 2. They've changed plenty of things in Scholar of the First Sin. But I guess that helps.

Comment: I had to upvote this back to zero since how these stupid golems work are really obscure.  I had to watch a walkthrough video before knowing what to do.

Comment: @Nelson Same, there are plenty of guides online for getting through this area, but none of them apply to SOFTS. I could have sworn I ran into a game-breaking bug when I got to this area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scholar of the First Sin, the stone soldiers in the room with the stone golem no longer come to life. Instead, you'll need to proceed to the next room with the two iron chests. Two Masked Manikins will attack in this room, you'll need to lure them into the previous room. Kill one of them *right next to* the golem and he'll come to life and activate the elevator.

In the original version of Dark Souls 2, killing the stone soldiers in the same room will activate the golem.

Comment: Yeah, I found that out after the first answer. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate this golem by killing an enemy near him, to activate the elevator outside. If this is done correctly, the golem will receive the souls, not you.

[image: Golem for the elevator]

He can be found at the top of the ladder in the room with the elevator. Once you have activated him, you follow the path back around, ride the elevator up, and you will find a key in one of the chests at in the room at the top.

Comment: This answer is only valid for the original Dark Souls 2, not Scholar of the First Sin

Comment: @QuestionMarks I've edited the answer, and it should be applicable now. Personally, not having played SotFS, I was a bit confused by this question. But now it makes sense :)